# How to enable automatic migration in production

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I know the basics of enabling automatic migration using [this link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/automated-migration-in-code-first.aspx).

Could anyone tell what is the best way to enable automatic migration in production without any hassle and how to do the automatic migration in scenarios where the connection string is provided during runtime?

Comment: I'll strongly recommend to not use automatic migrations in production. If you want to have full control about how your data model evolves it's better to create migrations and run them against the production database when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The EF DB version check will be performed at runtime. If you have enabled migration in your project (like in the link you provided, with MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion), migration will be applied on first context initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

I have this in place for my production platform, note that the command is only executed when the build is done in something other then debug mode.

```
#if !DEBUG
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<VerbekeContext, Default.Migrations.Configuration>());
#endif
```

this is added in my global.asax of an MVC project in the startup function, so if you have any other application you should execute this @ startup

Or you could set the AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true in the configuration.cs in the migrations folder. If you add the debug switch, set it to false in debug and true in other build modes.

```
namespace Default.Migrations
{
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Context>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Context context)
    {
       ///
    }
}
}
```